# How to read cert files from Cloud Functions for Firebase Folder

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to read a file under certs folder as shown below:

```
-functions
 |
--certs
  |
---idp-public-cert.perm
```

Here is the code I am using to read the file:

`fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs/idp-public-cert.pem'))`.

When I run the function, I get the following errors:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/srv/lib/certs/idp-public-cert.pem'
```

I would appreciate any crew on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear on your directory structure. I would guess do this: `fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'functions/certs/idp-public-cert.pem'))`

Answer (score 4):

Just read the file using the relative path `certs/idp-public-cert.pem`.  All relative paths will be interpreted relative to your deployed functions folder.  Don't try to build a full path to the file, as you shouldn't assume where your code deployment is effectively mounted in the server instance.

Comment: `fs.readFileSync( './certs/idp-public-cert.pem')` works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that specifying path with "./" or "/" is iffy - because it takes a relative patch from somewhere, maybe OLDPWD or PWD, not sure how it messes up
But I found that the right way to do fix is to add
__dirname to the path. __dirname will give the path of the functions directory.
so if your function is in /home/username/firebase/functions/routes, then __dirname will show you that.
So if you have a file /home/username/firebase/abc/, then you would have to specify:
fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"../abc/"

Hope this saves the time of others!! I wasted so much time on this, it was quite frustrating, and was kicking myself for not reading the doc!

Comment: See the comment left by John Hanley on Jan 24 '19 that covers this and shows how to use `path.join`